# How to ignore file name extensions while replacing source files for online editing in Premiere?

Tags: editing, video-editor, premiere, file-formats, encoding

I'm encoding all my source files for offline editing with Premiere Media Encoder. I have MP4 and MTS files, and I thought of converting them all to AVI DV-PAL.

Problem is I guess I'll have some problems when I'd like to replace the files back to original resolution, because of the different file names.

How should I approach this? Is there a way to ignore file name extenstions while replacing source files for online editing in Premiere?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Replace Footage" (right click on a source clip in the project) to swap a file with another file, but I don't know of a good automated way to do a bunch of files at the same time.  I think it might be a manual process to wire up the clips unfortunately.